# I have to apply the same number filter condition in 2 columns in excel across multiple sheets…is there any vba code available?

Tags: excel

I have to apply 2 numeric filter say >58300 and <-58300 in separate columns in worksheet and need to apply this same to 70 tabs. If any vba code is available please share

I tried a macro code but is only for 1 criteria

Comment: Hi, Yes there is vba code available but you need to show what you've tried and be more specific to get better help from the community.